# iOS "More" Tab remember last open page issue (xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, tabbedpage

I have an issue that on iOS "More" Tab behave strangely.
Using TabBar and TabbedPages.

When I start the app, I see 4 tabs (1-4) and "More" tab (Which is created automatically by xamarin.forms).
I open the "More" tab to see a list of rest tabs that don't fit. I will see my list "TabPage5" and "TabPage6".  (diagram bellow)

I choose for example TabPage5. After that, I will visit one of the tabs which are on the main bar (tabPage1-4).
And when I try to open the "More" tab again to see a list of TabPage5 and TabPage6 -> I am already on the detail of TabPage5 (as last opened from More tab).

It seems that it remembers which I visited last time or I didn't leave that page from the More tab properly.

Tabs bar:

- TabPage1
- TabPage2
- TabPage3
- TabPage4
- More

  - TabPage5
  - TabPage6

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Can anyone give me some advice about that. I would like always when I click on tab "More" to see list of tabs which were not default visible.
Thanks

Comment: That's the default behavior and I think it is by design. If you open detail page in TabPage1, then go to TabPage2 and go back to TabPage1, you will see the detail page instead of the first page of TabPage1.

Comment: Yes, I know. But is there way how to "overwrite" this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom renderer of `TabbedPage` and call `PopToRootViewController` when you select tabs in "More" tab:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.iOS
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        MainPage _page;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
                _page = e.NewElement as MainPage;
            else
                _page = e.OldElement as MainPage;

            try
            {
                if (ViewController is UITabBarController tabBarController)
                    tabBarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }


        void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Tab Tapped");

            var tabbarVC = ViewController as UITabBarController;

            var tabIndex = tabbarVC.SelectedIndex;

            if (tabIndex == null || tabIndex > 3)
            {
                tabbarVC.MoreNavigationController.PopToRootViewController(false);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```